# Extract edges between terms of a field based on another field[s] in elastic-graph

Tags: elasticsearch, graph

I illustrate my question with an example.
Assume having a type named "post". Each post has a userid field which indicates its author. This is how the post is stored:

```
{
   "_index": "test",
   "_type": "post",
   "_id": "10098259467307",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
     "text": "user 1 message",
     "userid": 1,
     "id": 10098259467307,
}}
```

Is there a way to extract the relationship between the users based on the co-occurrence of terms within the "text" field of posts which they have authored?
For example, if there are two posts containing the word "elastic", what I would like to see is an edge between the posts' authors.

Comment: You might be interested to check ES Graph out: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/graph/current/index.html

Comment: @Val I have already checked it. My question is whether it is possible to achieve what I need using ES Graph.